# Integration of Rotation matrix (Discrete implementation)

Tags: matrices, integration

this is my first question here. Hope you can help :)

I was implementing a research paper when I ran into this equation.

$ \Phi = { }^{I_n}_{G}R \int^{t_{n+1}}_{t_n} { }^{I_n}_{I_\tau}R d\tau $

Here $ { }^{I_n}_{G}R $ and $ { }^{I_{n+1}}_{G}R $ are known rotation matrices from an IMU (hence the $ \mathtt{I} $) at two different time steps and there is no information in between. $ { }^{I_n}_{I_\tau}R $ is the rotation from $ I_\tau $ to $ I_n $. So what does it mean to integrate the rotation matrix between these two time steps? How would the discreet implementation be done? I'm pretty sure the result should be a rotation matrix.

Comment: Perhaps by a quaternion integration approach? See [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00707-013-0914-2#page-1) for instance.

Comment: Nevermind, I just ended up using trapezoidal integration, because the difference between $ t_n $ and $ t_{n+1} $ is very small. Thanks for the comment, though.